# MYSQL Query To Retrieve The Same Results Each Time It Is Run

Tags: mysql

For the query below I am trying to retrieve a list of computer with `lastheatbeattime` greater than 10. I want the same results to be returned each time I run the query. At the moment the below code retrieves the same results multiple times but then changes.

I am not very experienced at SQL so simple responses are preferable.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS TestValue,
locations.name AS IDentityField,
(SELECT c.computerid FROM computers ORDER BY c.computerid DESC LIMIT 1) AS ComputerID, 
locations.locationid AS LocationID,
acd.NoAlerts,
acd.UpTimeStart,
acd.UpTimeEnd 
FROM
Computers c 
JOIN AgentComputerData acd 
ON (c.computerid = acd.computerid) 
JOIN heartbeatcomputers 
ON c.Computerid = heartbeatcomputers.computerid 
JOIN locations 
ON c.`LocationID` = locations.`LocationID` 
JOIN v_extradatalocations 
ON c.`LocationID` = v_extradatalocations.`locationid` 
WHERE c.os LIKE '%Windows Server%' 
AND LastHeartbeatTime < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 10 MINUTE) 
AND v_extradatalocations.`Server Service Plan` LIKE "%Managed 24x7%" 
AND locations.locationid != 154
GROUP BY c.`LocationID` 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.computerid) > 1 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT c.`ClientID`) < 20;
```

Comment: Could you describe the database structure, please?

Comment: How so? It's a Labtech (RMM Tool) database if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the results more deterministic if you add an `ORDER BY` clause - without this the order is random (and generally related to the fastest way SQL can execute the query).

Comment: I have an order by in the sub query? Do you mean add and order by to the main query? If so where would I add it?

Comment: The order by in the sub query is doing nothing as you are limiting that query to one row anyway. The order by needs to be last since it orders the information that was selected by the rest of the query. so adding 'ORDER BY ComputerID DESC' to the end of the query would be a good plan

Comment: 'HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.computerid) > 1 
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT c.`ClientID`) < 20
    ORDER BY c.computerid DESC;'

Comment: woops, so the end of the query looks like that and it's giving an invalid syntax error? Also I probably should have specified I only want to retrieve one result from many. But I want it to be the same result each time.

Comment: So worked out the error, now have ORDER BY c.computerid at the end of the query but the results are still alternating?

Comment: so what is your new query?

Comment: you can update the original question. I would expect, looking at the query, that the ordering would now be consistent but obviously the returned data changes if the underlying data is changing - that is what SQL does :-)

Comment: I don't believe the underlying data is changing as the results are always the same set of results but it seems the order of the results is what is changing for some reason?

Comment: Or possibly the lastheartbeat time is what's causing the issue.. as it is a time variable.. But it seems to alternate between the results as i'm hitting f9 to execute the query? This is doing my head in haha..

Answer (score 0):

Looking more closely you want to do this:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS TestValue,
locations.name AS IDentityField,
c.computerid AS ComputerID,
locations.locationid AS LocationID,
acd.NoAlerts,
acd.UpTimeStart,
acd.UpTimeEnd
FROM
Computers c
JOIN AgentComputerData acd
ON (c.computerid = acd.computerid)
JOIN heartbeatcomputers
ON c.Computerid = heartbeatcomputers.computerid
JOIN locations
ON c.`LocationID` = locations.`LocationID`
JOIN v_extradatalocations
ON c.`LocationID` = v_extradatalocations.`locationid`
WHERE c.os LIKE '%Windows Server%'
AND LastHeartbeatTime < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 10 MINUTE)
AND v_extradatalocations.`Server Service Plan` LIKE "%Managed 24x7%"
AND locations.locationid != 154
GROUP BY c.`LocationID`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.computerid) > 1
AND COUNT(DISTINCT c.`ClientID`) < 20
ORDER BY c.computerid DESC;
```

Your nested select was grabbing a random row since there was nothing to tie it to the rest of the query.

Comment: OK, actually, on closer inspection, your whole query is rubbish :-). You need all the things you select to be in the GROUP BY or it will just show random rows for the other data

Answer (score 0):

Answer was so simple.. add max() to c.computerid AS ComputerID,
eg. MAX(c.computerid) AS ComputerID,

It was because I was mixing grouped and ungrouped columns so sql was returning "random" data.

Source: jkavalik - #mysql freenode IRC

Thanks,
Justin